# I am glad to have met you

Tags: grammar

If I met a person yesterday, could I say, now, `"I am glad to have met you"` ?

Or is it better to say: `It's been a pleasure to meet you`?

Answer (score 4):

If you met them yesterday, and you're talking with them today — and you actually want to express that you are glad to have met them, rather than just express a friendly and polite formality — you should say "I'm glad [that] we met [yesterday]". This is *especially* true if you want to say it when you are not parting from one another, and you wish to continue by explaining some reason why your meeting was timely or fortunate.

Comment: I agree. "I'm glad we met yesterday" is probably the best.

Answer (score 2):

I think the better one is..

"It's been a pleasure to meet you"

'I am glad to have met you' is far too formal and one would only say it if the person in question has had a considerable impact on him/her or helped him/her in some way.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, or if it is that I'm British, but 'It's been a pleasure meeting you' seems to flow a bit better than 'to meet you'.

Comment: Not a native speaker but felt the same, WS2.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm glad to have met you" sounds better. It's equivalent to saying "I'm glad to have known you."

I'd say "It's been a pleasure to meet you" just before saying goodbye to someone (e.g. at the end of a business meeeting).

Comment: ok. `"I'm glad to have met you" ` sounded weird to me, though!

Comment: Why would it sound weird? I'd say the use of the present perfect's quite elegant here.

Answer (score 0):

Further application:
It's been a pleasure reading your comment, WS2 - 
That does flow better than: It's been a pleasure to read your comment.

Answer (score -3):

I checked it out on my book and luckily found this. 

"Perfect form is required when the action The Infinitive expresses precedes the situation The Predicate conveys." 

*Source:张道真，2002(2007.3 reprint)，张道真实用英语语法，外教版，on page:301*

One example it provides on the same page


**"He was pleased to have made your acquaintance."**

So I think your first expression fit the context well.